# Parsing a flag with a list of values

Tags: bash, shell, getopts

I'm creating a bash script which involves parsing arguments. The usage would be:

```
$ ./my_script.sh -a ARG_1 -b ARG_2 [-c LIST_OF_ARGS...]
```

Using `getopts` I'm able to parse `-a` and `-b` and get their respective values `ARG_1` and `ARG_2`. If and only if user places `-c` as last argument, then I'm also able to get `-c` and create a list with all values in `LIST_OF_ARGS...`.

But I would not like to force user to insert `-c` as the last flag. For instance, it would be great if the script can be invoked this way:

```
$ ./my_script.sh -b ARG_2 -c V1 V2 V3 -a ARG_1
```

Here is my current code:

```
while getopts a:b:c opt
do
    case $opt in
        a)
            A_FLAG=$OPTARG
            ;;
        b)
            B_FLAG=$OPTARG
            ;;
        c)
            # Handle values as regular expressions
            args=("$@")
            C_LIST=()
            for (( i=$OPTIND-1 ; i <= $#-1 ; i++ ))
            do
                C_LIST=("${C_LIST[@]}" ${args[$i]})
            done
            ;;
        ?)
            usage
            ;;
    esac
done
```

Comment: `getopts` does not support multi-argument options. You essentially need to parse the arguments manually, count arguments that follow `-c` as arguments to that option until you reach another defined option or the end of the list.

Comment: In your existing code, you would be better off writing the simpler expression: `c) C_LIST=("$OPTARG" "${@:$OPTIND}");;` That will correctly handle the case `-cV1 V2 V3` and it's also a lot shorter. (Also, learn to use `+=` on arrays.) That doesn't answer your question, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my system, I haven a `/usr/share/doc/util-linux/examples/getopt-parse.bash` file. It puts the result of `getopt` into a variable, and set the positional parameters to that variable. Then uses a `switch` similar to yours, but uses `shift` to remove arguments when found.

You could do something similar, but for your `-c` option use `shift` until you get an option or run out of arguments.

---

Or it might be enough for you to use your current solution, but remember to *set* the `OPTIND` variable after the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You need to separate your detection of the `-c` flag with the processing associated with it.  For example, something like:

```
while getopts a:b:c opt
do
    case $opt in
        a)
            A_FLAG=$OPTARG
            ;;
        b)
            B_FLAG=$OPTARG
            ;;
        c)
            C_FLAG=1
            ;;
        ?)
            usage
            ;;
    esac
done

# discard all of our options.
shift `expr $OPTIND - 1`

if [ "$C_FLAG" = 1 ]; then
            # Handle values as regular expressions
            args=("$@")
            C_LIST=()
            for (( i=0 ; i <= $#-1 ; i++ ))
            do
                C_LIST=("${C_LIST[@]}" ${args[$i]})
            done
fi
```

This script doesn't collect all the non-option arguments until *after* processing all the command line options.

Comment: Your solution did not work as it does not handle the input `-a ARG_1 -c LIST_OF_ARGS... -b ARG_2`. After read arguments, the for loop is getting `-c LIST_OF_ARGS... -b ARG_2` but at that point I'd expect -b could already be parsed.

Comment: It wasn't clear from your question that you expected that particular permutation to work.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a question: why have a -c option at all?

If the full usage involves a list of values, why not just have no -c option and allow the -a and -b options only while the rest are regular args as in `./myscript.sh -a ARG_1 -b ARG_2 [argument ...]`, where any arguments are optional (like the -c option and its arguments are in your usage example?

Then your question becomes "how do I intersperse program options and arguments", to which I would respond: "You shouldn't do this, but to achieve this anyway, parse the command line yourself; `getopts` won't work the way you want it to otherwise."

Of course, parsing is the hard way. Another possibility involves adding the values after -c to a list, so long as you don't encounter another option or the end of the options:

```
C_LIST=()
while getopts a:b:c: opt; do
    #Skipping code...
    c)
        C_LIST+="$OPTARG"
        shift $(expr $OPTIND - 1)
        while [ -n "$1" ] && [ $(printf "%s" "$1" | grep -- '^[^-]') ]; do
            C_LIST+="$1"
            shift
        done
        OPTIND=1
        ;;
```

The behaviour of getopts is mimicked: even if OPTARG begins with a '-' character, it is still kept, but after OPTARG, any string starting with the '-' character may simply be an invalid option such as -n. I used printf instead of echo because some versions of echo, such as the one that bash has built-in, have a -e option that may or may not allow the loop to continue, which isn't desired. The grep expression should prevent this, but who knows if that version of echo allows for -e'hello', which would cause grep to succeed because it sees "hello"? While possibly unnecessary, why take chances?

Personally, I'd avoid this behaviour if you can, but I also don't understand why you're asking for this behaviour in the first place. If I were to recommend anything, I'd suggest the more common `/path/to/script -a ARG_1 -b ARG_2 [argument ...]` style above any other possible choice of implementation.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg certainly `/path/to/script -a ARG_1 -b ARG_2 [argument ...]` will fit my needs. But in a generic way, it would not fit the usage `/path/to/script -a ARG_1 -b ARG_2 [-c LIST...] [-d ANOTHER_LIST...]. Apparently @larsks's solution will work